# java.lang.VerifyError in 2.2.2 but not 2.3.3

Tags: android

I am building for minSDK 8 and targetSDK 11.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"
          android:targetSdkVersion="11"/>
```

I get this in logcat:

```
WARN/dalvikvm(2114): VFY:  rejected Lcom/examplecompany/project/TidalStreams/Data/gTidalStreamsHourlyHW;.<clinit> ()V

WARN/dalvikvm(2114): Verifier rejected class Lcom/digitaliridium/tides/TidalStreams/Data/gTidalStreamsHourlyHW;
```

I have two Desires, amongst several other devices; one running 2.2.2 and one running 2.3.3.

On 2.2.2, I get a `java.lang.VerifyError` at this line:

```
public void onCreate(){
    ...

    gTidalStreamsHourlyHW.init();

    ...
}
```

Here's the the `init()` method.  it's the only method of a very ordinary class.

```
public static void init(){


    int insertPosition;
    System.arraycopy(gTidalStreamHourlyHW1, 0,  gTidalStreamHourlyHW, 0, gTidalStreamHourlyHW1.length);

    insertPosition = gTidalStreamHourlyHW1.length;
    System.arraycopy(gTidalStreamsHourlyHW2.gTidalStreamHourlyHW1, 0,  gTidalStreamHourlyHW, insertPosition, gTidalStreamsHourlyHW2.gTidalStreamHourlyHW1.length);

    insertPosition += gTidalStreamsHourlyHW2.gTidalStreamHourlyHW1.length;
    System.arraycopy(gTidalStreamsHourlyHW3.gTidalStreamHourlyHW1, 0,  gTidalStreamHourlyHW, insertPosition, gTidalStreamsHourlyHW3.gTidalStreamHourlyHW1.length);

    ...
```

`gTidalStreamsHourlyHW` is a large array of data, approx 350k.  I have had to split it into multiple files to get around Java's 64k compilation unit limit.

The `init` method simply uses System.arraycopy() to concatenate these multiple static arrays into one.

I've tried dropping the minSDK level to 7 but the problem is the same.

It also fails in an emulator running 2.2.2.

Comment: It seems that Android 2.2 doesn't have some methods. If you can write a workaround for 2.2 - you can check a version and run different methods.

Comment: @vorrtex But the project SDK is set to 8.  Any missing methods would cause a compile time error wouldn't they?  I've also have dropped the SDK to 7 and still get the crash.

Comment: The arrayCopy method is supposed to work at any API. Try to find exactly which line of the `init` method fails. Comment all lines at check if it works, then uncomment some lines and check again, after several iterations you will find out the wrong line.

Comment: FWIW the message does not say that it's rejecting `init()`. It's rejecting some code in the class's static initializer. This can be a `static` initializer block or any other initialization of static members.

Comment: @SeanOwen Thanks.  I got that it's not rejecting `init` but your steer to the static initialiser is spot on.  I've commented it out and the exception is gone - albeit my code no longer works ;).  I'll find out what's going on and post back.  The initialiser is nothing more than array initialisation.  What was the clue that the problem was the initialiser?

Comment: @SeanOwen.  Sean, it was your clue that led to the solution.  Please post an answer describing what indicated a problem in the static initialiser and I'll accept it.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Simon I think your answer is 90% of the actual, well, answer. Perhaps I can edit a word of explanation into that instead.

Comment: if you still at the beginning of building the application then i recommend you to test every method you create to confirm whether it works or no. for me it was tooo late so i had to remove 2.2 from my app support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a big Android fan but sometimes it's indefensible :(

There's a clue in the error that indicates that the error concerns static initializers; it's the `<clinit>` "method" name in:

```
WARN/dalvikvm(2114): VFY:  rejected Lcom/examplecompany/project/TidalStreams/Data/gTidalStreamsHourlyHW;.<clinit> ()V
```

This indicates that the error may have to do with a `static { ... }` initializer block, or initialization of some `static` class member.

My class has a static array initialiser:

```
 public static shcTidalStreamPointStruct[] gTidalStreamHourlyHW1  = new shcTidalStreamPointStruct[]{

            new shcTidalStreamPointStruct("000A",48.766667,-10.066667,51.116667,1.316667,"89",95,0.8,0.4,125,0.9,0.4,172,0.7,0.4,216,0.7,0.4,242,0.8,0.4,261,0.9,0.4,281,0.7,0.4,305,0.7,0.4,339,0.6,0.3,14,0.6,0.3,58,0.6,0.3,71,0.7,0.3,91,0.7,0.4,"GB",0),
            new shcTidalStreamPointStruct("000B",49.533333,-9.983333,51.116667,1.316667,"89",122,0.6,0.3,166,0.8,0.4,192,0.9,0.4,213,0.9,0.5,239,0.9,0.5,255,0.9,0.5,286,0.9,0.4,330,0.7,0.4,9,0.9,0.4,38,1,0.5,52,1.1,0.5,68,0.9,0.5,104,0.6,0.3,"GB",0),
            new shcTidalStreamPointStruct("000C",48.898333,-9.163333,51.116667,1.316667,"89",102,0.4,0.2,118,0.6,0.3,172,0.7,0.4,197,0.7,0.4,212,0.7,0.4,250,0.7,0.4,283,0.5,0.3,321,0.3,0.2,337,0.5,0.3,13,0.7,0.4,33,0.7,0.4,54,0.5,0.3,98,0.4,0.2,"GB",0),
```

There are 283 elements.

I built a test project with only this code and verified that on 2.2 and below, it fails.  On 2.3 and above, it works.

The problem is the number of lines in the initialiser!  I took out one line at a time until I was left with 197 lines and it works!

So as well as Java's 64k compilation unit limit, there is some undocumented limit (or bug) in the Android class loader related to the number of lines/size of the static initialisation.

The fix was to further split my files to reduce the line count.  Fugggllly....